# C# selenium raspberry pi

Tags: c#, selenium, mono, raspberry-pi

I cant find any information about selenium running on raspberry and C#(mono).

Is it possible to run tests with this stack of technologies and hardware?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, I using this stack of technologies:

- Ubuntu Mate as operation system
- C#, Mono
- Selenuim
- Phantom JS as selenium driver (you can get compiled version here https://github.com/piksel/phantomjs-raspberrypi)

I test it on Raspberry PI 3 model B and it works fine